# Conditional Eval in Gridview Template row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having an issue that I am certain is easy to resolve, I just don't know what to do.
Here is my code:

```html
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="text_shipped" Text="Media Shipped" runat="server" />
        <br />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_shipped" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipped") %>' />--></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="lnk_ship" runat="server" CssClass="btn-mini" Text="Ship Software" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipped" ) == "Yes" ? true : false %>' />--></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The label "lbl_shipped" is showing the correct value which is either "Yes" or "No" 
but, i want to add a button "lnk_ship", based on whether
 or not the value is "Yes" (show button), or "No" (do not show button).

My issue is that I am using conditional code on the Visible keyword and I am testing for the value, but it seem to be ignoring my value for "shipped"

here are the main two lines, the first one shows the value, the second line is conditional, the conditional is NOT working. it keeps showing false:

```html
<asp:Label ID="lbl_shipped" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipped") %>' />
<asp:Button ID="lnk_ship" runat="server" CssClass="btn-mini" Text="Ship Software" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipped" ) == "Yes" ? true : false %>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just mocked up something quickly and it is working for me (ASP.NET web forms targeting .NET 4, VS2012) , maybe have a look:

### Default.aspx

Contains the following `GridView` definition which I stuck randomly in a new web forms project.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridMe" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnName" Text="Hi" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name").ToString() == "Bob" %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Default.aspx.cs

Has the following class definitions

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var list = new List<Thing>
            {
                new Thing() {ID = 1, Name = "Bob"},
                new Thing() {ID = 2, Name = "Geraldine"}
            };
        gridMe.DataSource = list;
        gridMe.DataBind();
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Result

My output is something like:

```
ID  Name
1   [Hi]
2
```

Comment: Thank you Scotty ... I found the issue. it was stupid really, my value that I was testing for was "Yes", but the value in the Sql table had 7 trailing blanks. But, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel - my pleasure. sometimes having something really simple to compare to helps you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipped" ).ToString()
```

Add .ToString() ie:

```
<asp:Button ID="lnk_ship" runat="server" CssClass="btn-mini" Text="Ship Software" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "shipped" ).ToString() == "Yes" ? true : false %>' />
```

Comment: Thank you Irfan, unfortunately the button is still not showing on the Yes lines. I do appreciate the help, i will keep trying.

Comment: Make sure the css-class doesn't have display:none @PaulT.Rykiel

Comment: I wanted to let you know that I found the problem... I was able to add a method in the code behind and run debug, as it turned out the String was "Yes" but it had trailing spaces. so, its value is "Yes       ". but, I want to say thank you for all of your assistance. Best Regards

Comment: @IrfanTahirKheli - +1 from me as well as you spotted the `.ToString()`.